# For testing GPS based J2ME app, Is there any emulator which have built in GPS?

Tags: java-me, gps, emulation, nokia-s40, here-api

I am new in J2ME app development field. I am developing GPS based app using Nokia Maps for series 40 mobiles. I want such emulator which provide GPS(to retrieve & set current coordinates & many other purposes). I search a lot on google but I didn't found such emulator.... even what ever emulators provide by Nokia SDKs; they also don't have GPS capability... Then how should I get such emulator??

Comment: Have you tried Samsung or Sony SDKs?

Comment: Not yet... is they have in build GPS capability.. and if they have then from where i download that SDKs??

Answer (score 2):

You can download the latest Nokia IDE (which includes the Nokia Maps Plugin) here:
[Emulator download](http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/d312c223-c68a-447e-b295-c3a9ebc4b630/Nokia_SDK_2.0_for_Java_offline_installer_win.html)

The emulator associated with the SDK includes tools to simulate JSR-179 location calls (e.g. Cell-Id/GPS), you can play back coordinates for a saved file and receive them at regular intervals. Look at the emulator's Tools > Route Editor menu.

The confusion here is the difference between **GPS** positioning and **Cell-Id** positioning. There are currently no series 40 mobiles (that I know of) with a GPS unit - hence positioning will need to be done by Cell-ID -  In this case the only way to retrieve frequent location updates in the Cell-ID scenario is to call the `getLocation()` method within a repeating loop. Retrieving location objects via the `locationUpdated()` method, can only be done in a GPS-based location retrieval.

In summary you can get a **location** from any Java ME phone supporting JSR-179, you won't be using GPS though.

To get a location use the following:

```
 cellIdLocator = getCellIdProvider();
 cellIdLocator.getLocation(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
```

Where the cell-id provider can be held in a singleton

```
private LocationProvider cellIdLocator;

public LocationProvider getCellIdProvider() throws LocationException {
            if (cellIdLocator == null) {
                int[] methods = {
                    Location.MTA_ASSISTED | Location.MTE_CELLID
                            | Location.MTY_NETWORKBASED};

                cellIdLocator = LocationUtil.getLocationProvider(methods, null);
            }
            return cellIdLocator;
        }
```

Comment: But Somewhere I read that CellID always doesn't give you correct position.... How much is this true???

Comment: Cell-ID could give you an accuracy up to 100m (Urban Areas) it is less accurate in Rural Areas see: -                             http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Determining_Current_Location_via_Cell_ID  and http://cens.ucla.edu/~mhr/cs219/location/trevisani04.pdf - this was a case study in 2004, accuracy is likely to have improved since then.  Besides which you haven't got much of a choice - if the phone doesn't have a GPS unit, you will have to use Cell-ID